# Insert into table SET - rows with special characters skipped

Tags: mysql, special-characters

I have this query:

$sql = "
            INSERT INTO table SET 
                name = '$name',
                sku = '$number',
                  description = '$desc'
    ";

But the rows containing some special characters (in my case this ') are not inserted.. How I can solve?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm assuming you don't have any error reporting, because MySQL doesn't "skip" things. It might fail silently without you knowing. Let it out! Your db class will have a method for the error message. Using PDO or MySQLi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you construct your query, you need to escape the data you are inserting.
You need to at least use addslashes() function in PHP, like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table SET name = '".addslashes($name)."', sku = '".addslashes($number)."', description = '".addslashes($desc)."'";
```

However more correct way is to use a different function than addslashes, which would properly handle all characters in the data, not only apostrophes.

I am using my custom 'escape' function like this:

```
function escape($text)
{
   return str_replace(array('\\', "\0", "\n", "\r", "'", '"', "\x1a"), array('\\\\', '\\0', '\\n', '\\r', "\\'", '\\"', '\\Z'), $text);
}
```

So using this function, you would write:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table SET name = '".escape($name)."', sku = '".escape($number)."', description = '".escape($desc)."'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use parameterised queries instead of manually appending those values. Currently if name, number or description would contain any sql it would get executed.

A lot more detailed answer is in [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: good point! +1 from me for that tip. the OP really should look into avoiding SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

Read about escaping characters in mysql. I think it is done with `\`

Comment: Yes.. it works.. it's well to use with all the $data?

Comment: should be fine. in Mysql you can also use two ': ```''```

Comment: Read from xml with simplexml_load_file